# How to occupy empty screen real estate in a multi column layout?

Tags: html, r, layout, shiny

The sample code below generates a UI with some text in one column and image on the other column.

```
library(shiny)
library(stringi)

ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(6,
               h4('Text Section'),
               p(stri_rand_lipsum(2)),
               p(stri_rand_lipsum(2))),
        column(6,
               img(src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/200x200')
    )
))

server = function(input,output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Depending on the width of the page the first column can be longer or shorter than the image in the second column. Below is a case where the first column is longer.

[image: application output]

Question is, is there a layout that'll allow the text of the first column to occupy the empty space left in the second column as shown in the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you could do that is by removing your extra column grid and then putting all in the same with image aligned to right.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(stringi)

ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(8,
           h4('Text Section'),
           img(src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/200x200', align = 'right'),
           p(stri_rand_lipsum(2)),

           p(stri_rand_lipsum(2)))



  ))

server = function(input,output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for arbitrary divs? Seems like aligning a div right doesn't act the same way as aligning an image